# Rails Asset Pipeline with Sub-domains not retrieving Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have begun using the Rails Asset Pipeline in my application. It is working great for stylesheets and javascripts but I cannot get my images to be returned successfully. I think I understand why but I don't know how to fix it.

My application using subdomains: bob.myapp.com/, mandy.myapp.com/, etc. When I put an image_tag link within a view, e.g. link_to `image_tag('remove.png'...)` it is rendered with the HTML attribute `src="/assets/remove.png"`. Reasonable, however, this means the location that the browser is looking is: http://bob.myapp.com/assets/remove.png

If I paste that directly into my address bar, it is not found. If I change the subdomain to http://www.myapp.com/assets/remove.png (i.e. switching **bob** to **www**) the image is retrieved successfully.

So, how do I force my `image_tag` to seek a source from **www** or can I somehow make the asset pipeline work off of all subdomains by default?

Rails 3.1.0
Ruby 1.9.2p0

Answer (score 1):

You might want to set the host of assets in your `config/environments/production.rb` (or any other environments you defined).

For example:

```rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://www.myapp.com"
end
```

Since it accepts a `Proc`, you can do some computation there and set different hosts for assets:

```rb
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new do |source|
    subdomain = compute_subdomain(source)
    "http://#{subdomain}.myapp.com"
  end
end
```

The `image_tag(source, options)` helper will respect it and output full url for assets.

Although in my humble opinion, I suggest placing all assets on every asset server, that way there is no need to set this.